# Use JWplayer inside Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, jwplayer

how to run jwplayer with RecyclerView?

how to play only one video at a time and stop other videos in recycler view?

Answer (score 2):

The real question is "Do you really need the player inside of the RecyclerView?" It's not really recommended to have multiple video players instantiated at a time.
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/273#issuecomment-72432393
A better way to solve this problem would be to have a single player and set the playlist data as the RecyclerView data, loading the appropriate video into the player whenever selected.

Comment: I initiate player when user click on one of recycler items. my main question is that how can i stop the first video or make it null when the second item is clicked? thank you.

Comment: You would call stop(),onPause(),onDestroy(),remove the player from the ViewHolder, set the player to null. That will kill it.

https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/reference/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/JWPlayerView.html#onPause() https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/reference/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/JWPlayerView.html#onDestroy()